# Couldn't detect F11 keypress in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

*keypress*, *keydown*, *keyup* - none of these events get triggered when <kbd>F11</kbd> key is pressed both in Mac and Windows. Is this the expected behavior?

I have created a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/brindhaa10/kde3L0pg/)

```js
var logSpace = document.getElementById("log");

var log = function(event) {
  console.log(event.type, event);
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerText = event.type + ":" + event.code;
  logSpace.appendChild(p);
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", log);
```

Answer (score 0):

the logSpace element is not defined in this context but without it your code works just fine in Chrome/Windows

```js
var logSpace = document.getElementById("log");

var log = function(event) {
  console.log(event.type, event);
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerText = event.type + ":" + event.code;
 // logSpace.appendChild(p);
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", log);
```